# Area of a parallelogram using Cross Product

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

How do you compute the area of the parallelogram with 4 arbitrary corners, say at (1,1,1), (2,3,4), (3,2,1), and (4,4,4) using a cross product? I understand with 3 corners but getting a little lost with 4.

Answer (score 3):

If it really is a parallelogram, you may ignore the fourth corner and do whatever it is you have figured out. The way to check that is:
$$ (1,1,1)+ (4,4,4) = (5,5,5) = (2,3,4) + (3,2,1),   $$
which confirms that it is a parallelogram.

To be specific, the first pair are opposite corners, and the other pair are opposite corners.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth corner is determined by the other three.  So pick any three and use your formula.  Just pretend you don't know the fourth.